# Time Complexity of $geoNear queries in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, big-o

I'm trying to find the time complexity of the $geoNear query in MongoDB. The reason is I'm trying to see if I should use a KD Tree with KNN to find points near or the mongo query to prevent a slowdown in our API.

Googling around I cannot seem to find this info.

Thanks

Comment: I don't think this is publicly stated.

Comment: From what I see in https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/tree/master/src/mongo/db/geo and  https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/tree/master/src/mongo/db/index it uses GeoHash and standard b+tree index for $geoNear sorting. Must be O(log n) for search, and you limit number of results (100 by default). I didn't look deep into the code tho. I might be wrong.

Comment: Don't know the time complexity but `$near` query has a memory leak. Our MongoDB server got OOM-killed continuously. 128 GB RAM and 107k documents in the collection. Here's a reproduction with 10k documents and 5k concurrent `$near` queries: https://serpapi.com/blog/the-downfall-of-mongodb-performance-2/#out-of-memory-test-on-near